# Missing Bower Dependency in Ember Unit Test

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am writing a unit test for a service that depends on a Bower component. In the browser, the service works fine. However, when I try to test the service in a unit test, it fails to find the Bower component. What do I need to configure to get the unit test to find the Bower component?

Comment: Is your service being initiated by an initializer/instance-initializer that wouldn't run in unit tests? Can you give further details? What error do you get? Which bower component are you using?

Comment: It is not being injected by an initializer. Also, I should note that my acceptance test is able to make use of that Bower component. For some reason the module is not available when the service tries to use it when running in the context of a unit test. This may be by design, but I need to figure out how to be able to allow this module in my unit test. The module is normally accessible as a global.

Comment: The Bower component that I'm working with is called Papa Parse, but I don't think that part is important. I have a custom "shim" file which adds the component files to the broccoli tree.

Comment: I got these errors too, but in my case, GitlabCI doesn't have run bower install before play tests.